# How to check what information httpie transfers to their own servers

Tags: privacy

Httpie is an HTTP client used by some developers to communicate with and test REST API and other services available through HTTP.

Every time I use httpie (https://httpie.io/) in addition to the server I specify, it also makes a connection to the their own server https://httpie.io

I am on macOS, and installed httpie using Brew.

I only imagine they are collecting some telemetry.

Has anyone looked at the information httpie is transmitting?
Is there a way to check what information httpie is transmitting?

I love the tool and use it rather frequently, but every time I feel I should look into this.

following comments, I looked at their source code here https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ahttpie%2Fhttpie+httpie.io+language%3APython&type=code&l=Python

There is a "check for updates" call that can be a candidate.

Comment: It is probably worth specifying exactly what product you are using.  If it is the OS cli then looking at the code would seem a good start.

Comment: Have you asked them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Man-in-the-Middle (MitM) proxy (e.g. Charles proxy; https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to inspect the requests made by `httpie`, which supports proxies (https://httpie.io/docs/cli/proxies). I would hope they honor the configuration for those additional requests.